# Is there a way to get pivot tables to repeat all row labels?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

When I move a a column label to row labels it creates a bunch of repeating values in the row labels, but excel leaves those empty.

http://screencast.com/t/tBuxJZze5YN

I'd like to have those filled out with repeating values as I need it on that format. Right now I'm using a script to fill out the empty cells with the value above it, but it seems there should be a simpler way but I couldn't find it under the design tab where I thought it would be.

Comment: Right click on the pivot table and check out the various Layout options available under Pivot Table Options.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

#### Option 1:

If you have Excel 2010 or later version, you can apply the 'Repeat Item Labels' functionality. This feature ensures that all item labels are repeated to create a solid block of contiguous cells in pivot.

```
- Place your cursor anywhere in your pivot table. 
- Then go up to the Ribbon and select Design -> Report Layout -> Repeat All Item labels.
```

#### Option 2:

Take advantage of Excel's GOTO Special functionality.

```
- First, turn pivot tables into hard data by doing a Copy-Past Special-Values on them. 
- Select the range you are working with, then go to the Home tab - > Find & Select -> Go to Special. This will activate the Go To Special dialog box.
-  Choose the option for Blanks. The result is that only the blank cells are selected. This is effectively the same as holding down the Ctrl key while selecting all the blank cells one by one with the mouse.
- Type an equal sign, and press the up-arrow key. The equal sign tells Excel that you're starting a formula in the active cell, while pressing the up-arrow key points to the cell above the active cell.
- Pressing 'Ctrl+Enter' enters the same formula in all the selected cells.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have an older version of Excel but option 2 worked great - thanks